# Shuffle.js - looking for a way to filter using <select>

Tags: javascript, select, filter, dropdown

I've been playing with Shuffle.js and really like how smooth it is. I'm looking for a way to filter the results using SELECT form field.

Second part of my question: Is this even a good idea to use SELECT to filer? I have successfully figured out how to filter using an unordered list as the dropdown, but the problem is the selected term doesn't stay highlighted when it collapses... which is why I'm looking at SELECT. I appreciate any feedback!

Here's what my code looks like (bootstrap 3 + wordpress):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Filter Field Notes Category <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu portfolio-sorting">
                    <li><a href="#" data-group="all" class="active">All</a></li>
                    <?php foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) { ?>
                    <li><a href="#" data-group="<?php echo $custom_term->slug ?>"><?php echo $custom_term->name ?></a></li>
                    <?php }  ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/

**------------------------UPDATE------------------------**

So I've been searching for a couple of hours today and decided to give up on trying to use Select dropdown, and shifted my attention to trying to simulate it instead. This is a great workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/a6NJk/2/

It is quite a simple and elegant solution using jQuery and some JS. Just had to replace the data-group variables in each list item and it works great to filter with Shuffle.js. Hope this helps anyone looking to do the same!

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="init">[SELECT]</li>
    <li data-value="value 1">Option 1</li>
    <li data-value="value 2">Option 2</li>
    <li data-value="value 3">Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul { 
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}
ul li { padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 2; }
ul li:not(.init) { float: left; width: 130px; display: none; background: #ddd; }
ul li:not(.init):hover, ul li.selected:not(.init) { background: #09f; }
li.init { cursor: pointer; }

a#submit { z-index: 1; }
```

JS

```
$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.toggle();
});


$("#submit").click(function() {
    alert("The selected Value is "+ $("ul").find(".selected").data("value"));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround and have edited my original post. Hope it helps!